# Custom DNS server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, bind, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a custom DNS server for my domain on an AWS EC2 Instance. The instance is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the DNS server is configured using bind 9. When I restart the bind server using

`sudo service bind9 restart`

The /var/log/syslog shows a successful start with no errors.

Now if I run a dig on the server itself like:

```
dig @localhost mydomain.com
```

I get the right response. Something like:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @localhost mydomain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15819
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 8abafb45d049d921010000006212f87a85a91753aaa86a24 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cirtructor.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.         604800  IN      A       99.99.999.999

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 21 02:27:06 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

But now when I run the dig command from another machine like:

```
dig @888.888.888.888 mydomain.com
```

Where I use my DNS server IP address in place of 888.888.888.888 I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @888.888.888.888 mydomain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I also tried doing dig from an instance on the same VPC. Something like:

```
dig @10.0.0.999 mydomain.com
```

Still was not able to make it work.

To check whether the DNS server is connected to the internet I opened port 88 in the security group of AWS and ran a http server on port 88. I could get to the http server easily by accessing http://888.888.888.888:88

So the server is connected but somehow the DNS queries do not reach it.

IP Tables policy is ACCEPT and no rules are added. Port 53 is open in the Security Group already.

What steps can I take to figure out what is going on? Is there a way to trace where the DNS lookup fails? Any help or suggestions would be extremely useful.

Comment: Why are you wanting to run your own DNS service? As an alternative, you might be able to use a **resolver**. See: [Resolving DNS queries between VPCs and your network - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html)

Comment: There are some reasons for running a DNS server. I need to be able to create subdomains on the fly and register them immediately and remove them from the DNS. Also there could be 100s of subdomains that I need to create at a particular time. So I felt running my own DNS server would be a better way to get more control over DNS entries and having no limit on the DNS entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of two scenarios, I had in the past, have you checked these?

- The route back to the querying system was not there/not working at all, so the DNS answers never made it back to the origin. Hence only the local lookup works, but inside the VPC and outside of it resolution doesn't work.
- There's some other service listening on UDP/TCP 53. I don't have any exact scenario in mind, where the bind service could respond with success but still can't listen on DNS ports, but I also can imagine that.

Tools I would use are tcpdump and traceroute.

Comment: The problem was TCP 53 was open but UDP 53 was not! Opening that in the Security Group made it work.

Comment: great to hear @Milind :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Modify the DNS attributes for your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html):

> Amazon provides a DNS server (the Amazon Route 53 Resolver) for your VPC. To use your own DNS server instead, **create a new set of DHCP options** for your VPC.

See also: [Add custom domain name resolution with DHCP options sets - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the lead. Although I still don't understand why doesn't only DNS request not reach the server while other request goes through I still went ahead and tried changing the DHCP Options sets and associate it with the VPC of my DNS server. The Public IP still resolves fine (tested it using the HTTP server method on port 88) but the DNS query is still not working :(

Comment: I don't know much about the details, but AWS always runs DHCP. When a computer connects to the network, it uses DHCP to obtain an IP address and is also informed about the DNS Server. That's when it knows to point to your DNS server instead of the one normally supplied. You can select the VPC, choose "Edit DNS resolution" and turn off the normal AWS DNS service in the VPC. However, I have never tried creating my own DNS service.